# Ecto.InvalidChangesetError on has_many relation when creating parent

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm currently working my way through the code in Programming Phoenix and I've hit upon an error that baffles me.

I get the following error when I run `Rumbl.TestHelpers.insert_user`

```
** (Ecto.InvalidChangesetError) could not perform insert because changeset is invalid.

* Changeset changes

%{name: "Some user", password: "supersecret", password_hash: "$2b$12$ZaSx6WcTZnrRGrneHsrNF.oMx8if3yMNssnx1B/lGBD5/GPj17Ym6", username: "user50853EBB5B75FC40"}

* Changeset params

%{"name" => "Some user", "password" => "supersecret", "username" => "user50853EBB5B75FC40"}

* Changeset errors

[videos: "is invalid"]

(ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:121: Ecto.Repo.Schema.insert!/4
```

`Rumbl.TestHelpers.insert_user` looks like this:

```
alias Rumbl.Repo

def insert_user(attrs \\ %{}) do
  changes = Dict.merge(%{
        name: "Some user",
        username: "user#{Base.encode16(:crypto.rand_bytes(8))}",
        password: "supersecret"
                   }, attrs)

  %Rumbl.User{}
  |> Rumbl.User.registration_changeset(changes)
  |> Repo.insert!()
end
```

`Rumbl.User`:

```
defmodule Rumbl.User do
  use Rumbl.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :username, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    has_many :videos, Rumbl.Video

    timestamps
  end

  def changeset(model, params \\ :invalid) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(name username), [])
    |> validate_length(:username, min: 1, max: 20)
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
  end

  def registration_changeset(model, params) do
    model
    |> changeset(params)
    |> cast(params, ~w(password), [])
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 6, max: 100)
    |> put_pass_hash()
  end

  defp put_pass_hash(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{valid?: true, changes: %{password: pass}} ->
        put_change(changeset, :password_hash, Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt(pass))
      _ -> changeset
    end
  end
end
```

And finally `Rumbl.Video`:

```
defmodule Rumbl.Video do
  use Rumbl.Web, :model

  schema "videos" do
    field :url, :string
    field :title, :string
    field :description, :string
    belongs_to :user, Rumbl.User
    belongs_to :category, Rumbl.Category

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc """
  Builds a changeset based on the `struct` and `params`.
  """
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:url, :title, :description], [:category_id])
    |> validate_required([:url, :title, :description])
    |> assoc_constraint(:category)
  end
end
```

I'd be really grateful to anyone who can shed some light on why I get this error.

Comment: With what arguments are you calling `insert_user`?

Comment: @Dogbert none, just the default.

Comment: somewhere you are passing in a :videos key that is invalid when creating a user. You need to search for it. Also as a side note, Dict has been deprecated in favor of Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that fixed it all was running `mix do deps.clean --all, deps.get, deps.compile && mix test`.

Comment: You can put `"reset": ["deps.clean --all", "deps.get", "deps.compile"]` as an entry in your `aliases` in `mix.exs` if it keeps happening ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your changeset:

> def changeset(model, params \\ :invalid) do

Your default value is the `:invalid` atom. I also followed the Programming Phoenix which says that you can pass :empty or :invalid atom. But `:empty` is not accepted anymore. So I also tested `:invalid`.

The problem is, when you passing no arguments, as you are doing, the :invalid makes the entire changeset invalid as you can see in the error message.

The solution in my case, and I think in yours too, is changing `:invalid` to `%{}`, then the changeset parameters will became an empty map but will be still valid. And it will works in your insert.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not correct. `TestHelpsers.insert_user` sends changes as params to registration_changeset which in turn passes it on to changeset. Which means that params will always be a dictionary with the following data: `%{name: "Some user", password: "supersecret", username: "user<rand_bytes>"}`.

Everything works fine if I remove the `has_many :videos` line.

Comment: if you add a video for the user with the insert_video, it works?

Comment: I had a similar problem and using `%{}` instead of `:invalid` fixed it for me. Thanks!